# OpenCV 2.2 installation - everything fine but debug output shows "cannot find or open PDB file"

Tags: .net, opencv, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have just installed the OpenCV 2.2 library with VS 2010 following the [willowgarage install guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++). at first no dll could be detected so I copied every .dll file in the OpenCV folder to Windows, system and system32 folders.

The sample and image output comes fine, however the debug output in Visual studio 2010 shows a series of .dll (including 'kernel32.dll') whose PDB files couldn't be found or opened. Now will this affect my development in any way, or should I just ignore it and get back to image processing proper?

Any way to work around this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue.
See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx

"The Visual Studio debugger uses the path to the PDB in the EXE or DLL file to find the project.pdb file."

Since these DLL files are not from your system they were likely not built to point to any PBD file on your system.  Maybe not even built to have debug info in them at all.

Answer (score 2):

(Just as an additional information for other users having the same question:) You can continue but debugging is a pain (you only get the failed assertions). If you want to be able to debug properly, you have to build OpenCV yourself. It is easier than it sounds: http://www.hasper.info/opencv-and-visual-studio-empty-call-stack/

1. Use CMake to configure a project for VS 2010
2. Ignore the warnings - Basically you can leave all the 3rd party libraries for optimization etc.. away. This makes the building much more easier. If your code is completely debugged, you can switch back to the prebuilt and optimzed version.
3. Add the folders containing the built dlls to your PATH